# Question about Pointers and Objects

Tags: c++

My last question was a mess. I'm getting the wrong output.

So here I have in my main:

```
image = QImage(width, height, 32); // 32 Bit
Color amb(0.1,0.1,0.1);
Color difCoef(0.75,0.6,0.22);
Color spec(0.5,0.5,0.5);
double shineExp = 3.0;
Sphere *s = new Sphere(Point(0.0,0.0,-5), 100.0, amb, difCoef, spec, shineExp);
shapes.push_back(s);
```

Where shapes is vector < Shape * >  shapes;

```
Shape *x = shapes[0];
cout << "Shine" << x->shine << endl;
```

Prints out zero even though the answer should be 3.0.

The following are my classes:

```
#include "shape.h"
class Sphere : public Shape
{
    public:
    Point centerPt;
    double radius;
    Color ambient;
    Color dif;
    Color spec;
    double shine;

    Sphere(Point center, double rad, Color amb, Color difCoef, Color specu, double shineVal)
    {
        centerPt = center;
        radius = rad;
        ambient = amb;
        dif = difCoef;
        spec = specu;
        shine = shineVal;
    }
```

---

```
class Shape
{
    public: 
    Shape() {}
    ~Shape(){} 
    Color ambient;
    Color dif;
    Color spec;
    double shine;
    virtual bool checkIntersect(Point p, Point d, Point &temp) = 0; // If intersects, return true else false.
    virtual Point getNormal(Point intPt) = 0; // Get the normal at the point of intersection
    //virtual void printstuff() = 0;

};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're repeating your variable declarations in the derived class.  You don't need to redeclare variables like `double shine`, which are already in `Shape`, in the derived class `Sphere`.  Since `Sphere` inherits from `Shape`, all the public member variables in `Shape` are automatically inherited in `Sphere`, and do not need to be redeclared.  Redeclaring them will result in *two* different member variables, i.e. `Sphere::shine` is a totally different variable from `Shape::shine`.

Therefore, when you assign a value to `Sphere::shine`, and then later access an instance of `Sphere` with a base-class `Shape` pointer, the value of `shine` is not going to be what you expect.

Comment: Thanks, such a better answer than the last post due to my insane ******* question :D

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of `Sphere` has two variables called `shine`. One is in the derived class and one is in the base class.

The `Sphere` constructor initializers the derived `Sphere::shine`, but `x->shine` accesses the base class variable, because `x` has type "pointer to `Shape`". Member variables don't have any 'virtual' behaviour.

I'm almost certain that what you want is to keep the common variables in the base class `Shape` and not redeclare identically named and type member variables in the derived class. You should only declare properties that are unique to the derived class in the derived class (such as `centerPt` and `radius` for `Sphere`).

Answer (score 1):

You should NOT redefine `shine` member in `Sphere`